# Platform cache org value available to other processes? (such as Dev console)

Tags: org, cache

Just curious on the visibility of a setting created in the platform org cache. I have a process that runs and creates this name-value pair and I then try interrogating it from the Dev Console and it does not find it. Are there known restrictions on the visibility/entitlements across processes?

process 1:

```
cache.Org.put(key, value, 300);
```

Dev Console Anonymous code:

```
cache.Org.get(key);
```

Comment: what type of "process" sets the value?  Are you sure you are checking it within 5 minutes of when it was set?

Comment: Vamsi - the process is just some apex code running in a helper class being called from a controller. Yes - I'm doing the Dev Console call within the timeout period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per arguments you have passed in method:

```
cache.Org.put(key, value, 300);
```

The "value" for "key" will be available for 5 minutes only. After that you will get `null`.

Try with following example:

```
cache.Org.put('local.Partition.pKey', 'value of key pKey', 300); // 5 min
System.debug(' => value is '+ cache.Org.get('local.Partition.v'));
```

then execute only one statement:

```
System.debug(' => value is '+ cache.Org.get('local.Partition.v'));
```

You will get `'value of key pKey'` if code execute within 5 minutes.

**Visibility**

> The org cache is not tied to any session and is available to the
>   organization across requests and to all users.

You would check that you are not setting session cache.

Comment: Ashwani, thanks. Yes - I ran my test within the expiration time specified but was getting a null every time.  Also - yes - I'm using the org cache rather than the session cache.

Comment: @Ram did you created partition before using it. Aslo it should have some capacity allocate.

Comment: Ashwani - yes - it could have been an issue with a typo in the key or may be I was indeed trying right after the expiration was done. I was able to successfully interrogate the org cache from the dev console. Thanks for your help! Thanks to Vamsi as well.